# Start RIAK DEV Nodes After Building From Source

Tags: ubuntu, cluster-computing, riak

I've downloaded and installed RIAK from GitHub, along with all necessary dependencies. RIAK install without issue. I ran the command **make devrel** to generate nodes 1 - 5 for development purposes.

When I CD into each directory and execute the riak start command, I receive the following:

*No command 'riak' found, did you mean:
 Command 'risk' from package 'xfrisk' (universe)
riak: command not found*

It seems that the OS can't execute the riak shell script in each directory. I'm deliberately building from source, as I'd like to review the clustering features of RIAK.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Having read through the riak shell script, it seems that the **riak start** command must be run from the parent directory in order to leverage adjacent binaries in the *etc* folder.

Comment: No, it doesn't. In fact, it has nothing to do with Riak at all. It means that `.` isn't in your shell path and you would need to be typing `./riak start`

Comment: Thanks, can you explain how and why to add this to the shell path please?